# COM Interop Rebuild/Clean not calling registration/unregistration issues

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, com-interop

I am writing a library add-in that uses COM Interop and I am having problems during the clean and rebuild tasks. Visual Studio 2019 is setup to run a external program to debug and runs the .dll registration after the build using `regasm` to write registry values for the external program. I am using the "Register for COM interop" option.

This is causing problems during the clean/rebuild tasks. If I run a clean/rebuild on the solution I receive `Access to the <dllPath> path is denied` but if I run a clean on each individual library or run a clean twice (first time gives errors, second time works) things seem to work but leaves the msbuild and VBCSCompiler services hung up after shutting down VS.

However if I unregister the library via the command line using `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm /unregister <dllPath>` before building the project, VS throws an error saying that the registry key doesn't exist, VS thinks it needs to unregister the library but the clean works as expected and removes the files in `bin/Debug`.

To run the registration I have:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <FrameworkSDKPath>
     $(registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework@InstallRoot)
  </FrameworkSDKPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PostBuildEvent>
   "$(FrameworkSDKPath)v4.0.30319\regasm" /codebase "$(TargetPath)"
</PostBuildEvent>
```

If I don't have the post build event it only registers the .dll in the GC but doesn't call the methods decorated with `[ComRegisterFunction]` and the external program doesn't recognize it. There are a couple of problems besides not deleting the files, if the decorated `[ComUnregisterFunction]` is not called (VS doesn't call this when cleaning/rebuilding) it will leave artifacts within the external programs registry entries, but it clears the GC entry.

Is there a way to get all this to sync up or do I need to revert to a total manual build process to take care of the registration? Is there an option to tell VS to call the register/unregister functions during the build/clean? Am I missing a step or a configuration setup?

Comment: If you use regasm (which you seems to need since you're using ComRegisterFunction), you don't need to use "Register for COM interop". Note you don't have to call regasm at each build, only from time to time if you change important COM information (like if you change interfaces layout and need a .TLB)

Comment: It may be better to use the inline c# compiler that give more options that the VS compiler.  You need to verify that the library is registered and only add registration when it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

As Simon pointed out, I didn't need to have the "Register for COM interop" option enabled since I was calling `RegAsm.exe` in the build, disabling this option allowed the files to be updated without any problems.